# Access Property of a List Item Model from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Javascript to edit the property of a row in a List of items and i am following a HTML view like this

ON edit button click i am showing a popup and on Save event of popup i want to set the properties of a selected row .

From html console i can see naming pattern is like name=[1].IsVerified [2].isVerified etc or in general [counter].Property  But when i try to access element using JQUery i am not getting the element

```
    @model  IList<RoyaltyDb.Models.VerifyLicensorModel> 
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
              Licensor
            </th>
            <th>
             Address
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Verify
            </th>
        </tr>
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
      {
            <tr>
                <td>         
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Licensor)                                                    
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Licensor)                                
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].Address)
                </td>
                <td>                              
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].IsVerified)                         
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsVerified, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
                    <br />                  
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ActionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ReferenceId)                                
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="SetProperties('@Model[i].Licensor')" class="btn">Verify</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>


    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="VerifyLicensorModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Verify  Licensor</h4>
                    <input type="hidden" id="targetPopup" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="VerifyLicensorDetails">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmLicensor()">Confirm</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    function SetProperties(name)
    {
        //Showing a POPUp Here on element  VerifyLicensorModal
    }
    function confirmLicensor()
    {
       //Set the corresponding IsVerified checkbox to true
      //Set values of ActionId and ReferenceId params in the hidden fields 
      //ActionId  ReferenceId
    }
```

So how can i set the value of a property field from javascript

Comment: Are you wanting to open the popup and populate its controls based in the values in the row the link is in?

Comment: Nope . I am getting value of first column which is passed via onclick inside popup [ which is a partial view] . On close of popup i want to rest the other fields in the selected row .  Question is how can i access the other elements I have a unique Id say TempId for every row  and thats also available. So i want a solution to access hidden field in row number

Comment: Don't try to use `id` attributes, instead use relative selectors (relative to the link you clicked). But you have disabled the checkbox so it value will not post back anyway.

Comment: But how can i keep track of selector .Since flow is like on click of anchor tag Popup will be visible [ Its a JQuery GET and calling a partial view].Now the flow of events are happening in popup only and after all data entry on popup form we are saving Popup data . So how can i keep selector all this time?

Comment: Have at look at the answer - but note the last paragraph - its not going to work as you think it will. Is the idea that you want a visual indication that you have done the verification but dont want the user to be able to check or uncheck the checkbox? If so let me know and I'll add a suggested alternative

Answer (score 1):

Rather than polluting your markup with behavior, use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Give you link a class name and add the value of the `Licensor` property as a `data-` attribute and move the 2 hidden inputs into the same table cell for easier selection

```
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ActionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ReferenceId)  
    <a href="#" data-licensor="@Model[i].Licensor" class="btn verify">Verify</a>
</td>

var currentCell;
$('.verify').click(function() {
  currentCell = $(this).closest('td');
  licensor = $(this).data('licensor');
  // get your partial view and display the popup
});
```

Similarly give the confirm button a unique `id` attribute

```
$('#confirm').click(function() {
  var inputs = currentCell.children('input');
  inputs.eq(0).val(....); // set the value of ActionId
  inputs.eq(1).val(....); // set the value of ReferenceId
});
```

Note that you question indicates *Set the corresponding IsVerified checkbox to true*. Because this is in the previous cell, you could do it using

```
currentCell.prev('td').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop(checked, true);
```

however you have disabled the checkbox using `new { @disabled = "disabled" }` which means it wont post back, but the associated hidden input generated by `CheckBoxFor()` will, meaning that irrespective of checking it, you will always post back `false`

If the checkbox is intended to give a visual representation that verification has been completed, then a better approach would be to include a hidden input bound to `IsVerified` and an unbound checkbox.

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
</td>
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ActionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ReferenceId)  
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].IsVerified)
    <a href="#" data-licensor="@Model[i].Licensor" class="btn verify">Verify</a>
</td>
```

Then you can 'check' the checkbox as noted above and include

```
inputs.eq(2).val("True"); // set the value of IsVerified
```

in the script

You may also want to consider deleting the 'Verify' link from the DOM once you close the popup (assuming you don't want to verify it again

```
currentCell.children('a').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>        
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) 

      {
            <tr>
                <td>       
                    <input typye="hidden" class="index" value="@i"/>  
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Licensor)                                                    
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Licensor ,{@id="liecenor-@i"})                                
                </td>
                            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
        </table>
<script>

    $(".table > tbody> tr").each(function () { 
    var index=$(this).find('.index').val();
    var $id="#licensor-"+index;    
    alert($($id).val());
}
</script>
```